# Removes non-vegetarian foods from a list of foods.

Tags: python, recursion

Removes non-vegetarian foods from a list of foods
by using  a list of Food objects
Uses a recursive algorithm
return only vegetarian foods.

Here is the question but it's confusing to me because it requires to use an auxiliary function.

Could someone explain it to me?

The list of foods in (food.txt) is looks like:

```
Spicy Vegetable Moo Shu|1|True|140

BBQ Pork|1|False|920
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear as it is, what do you want to be explained?

Comment: That list isn't even a valid list in python

Comment: Ask your [professor or a TA](http://bohr.wlu.ca/cp164/asgns/asgn07.php?d=2016-03-04) for clarification.  Or don't, as the description is on the page.

Comment: I mean, I want explain how can I write the code with an auxiliary function

Comment: The list is in the file that I have to work in it.

Comment: you'll have to start by reading the file first and making a list of vegetarian and non-vegetarian foods

Comment: So, what you're asking is the difference between a fruitful recursion function and an inplace recursion function?

Comment: no, I'm asking how can I write the code by using both recursion and an auxiliary function.

Comment: Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Example_programs Examples in Scheme. The first example shows the factorial function in "fruitful" recursion. The second example shows the same with an auxiliary function. It's almost like a while loop, except you keep track of where you are in the loop on the arguments used to call the auxiliary function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def veggie_r_ip(foods, curIndex):
    if(curIndex >= len(foods)):
        return
    curFood = foods[curIndex]
    is_veggie = curFood.split('|')[2]
    if is_veggie == "False":
        foods.remove(curFood)
        veggie_r_ip(foods, curIndex)
    else:
        veggie_r_ip(foods, curIndex + 1)

def main():
    foods =['Spicy Vegetable Moo Shu|1|True|140', 'BBQ Pork|1|False|920', 'Chicken Breast|1|False|920', 'Salad|1|True|920']
    veggie_r_ip(foods, 0)
    print foods
```

Comment: Thank you very much, know it's clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

When it says use recursion, it means you should call the function from within the function definition. For example, to get you started:

```
def recurse(inputs_list):
    if('b' in inputs_list):
        inputs_list.remove('b')
        return recurse(inputs_list)
    return inputs_list


inputs =['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'b']

print recurse(inputs)
```

Output:

```
>>['a', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f']
```

You use recursion because .remove() removes the first element that matches the search string.

Comment: you are right, but in the question it requires to use an auxiliary function with recursion.

Comment: What Auxilliary function? The description says: "Removes non-vegetarian foods from a list of foods. Uses a recursive algorithm.
    Use: veggie_r_ip(foods)", which is the exact same name as the parent function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `list`, you can use `recursion` as,

```
>>> foods = ['Spicy Vegetable Moo Shu|1|True|140', 'BBQ Pork|1|False|920', 'Chicken Breast|1|False|920', 'Salad|1|True|920']
>>> def veggie_r_ip(foods):
...         for f in foods:
...             is_veggie = f.split('|')[2]
...             if is_veggie == 'False':
...                 foods.remove(f)
...                 veggie_r_ip(foods)
...         return foods
... 
>>> veggie_r_ip(foods)
['Spicy Vegetable Moo Shu|1|True|140', 'Salad|1|True|920']
```

Comment: Where is the auxiliary function? :)

Comment: thank you, the trick is how to answer it with an auxiliary function.

Comment: I have difficulty to understand the auxiliary function